# $a_n =(\frac{n}{n+1})^n$ find convergence by geometric series

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

$a_n =(\frac{n}{n+1})^n$

I calculated  a few terms:

$a_1 = 1/2$
$a_2 = 4/9$
$a_3 = 27/64$

But not sure how to find $r$ so i can calculate its value as $n$ approaches infinity (if it does converge)

Comment: Your $a_3$ should be $27/64$. Also, it is not clear if you are talking sequences or series.

Comment: In any case, this sequence cannot be written as $\{ar^n\}$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Consider $$\frac 1{a_n}=\left(\frac{n+1}{n}\right)^n=\left(1+\frac{1}{n}\right)^n.$$ [It is well known](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/E_%28mathematical_constant%29) that this sequence converges to $e$. Hence, $a_n\to 1/e\approx0\mathord.368$ as $n\to\infty$.

Comment: very nice +1 $(1 + \frac{1}{n})^n$ was obvious but hadn't found a way to integrate it.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:**
$$\lim_{n\to{\infty}}{a_n}=\lim_{n\to{\infty}}\frac{1}{\left(1+\frac{1}{n} \right)^n}=\frac{1}{\lim\limits_{n\to{\infty}}\left(1+\frac{1}{n} \right)^n}=\frac{1}{e}.$$